# fbprophet: Error evaluating model log probability: Non-finite gradient

Tags: python, pandas, facebook-prophet

I am getting the following error:
[image]

All I am doing is running this piece of code. I have used this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/sandp500 but tried a few different ones, and all of them returned this message.

```
pandas_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
data_to_use = pandas_df.filter(['datetime', 'close'])
data_to_use.columns = ['ds', 'y']
data_to_use['ds'] = to_datetime(data_to_use['ds'])

model = Prophet()
model.fit(data_to_use)

future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
prediction = model.predict(future_dates)
```

I have installed pystan and fbprophet in a new conda environment, python 3.7.10, pystan 2.19.1.1, fbprophet 0.7.1.

I am not sure how to proceed, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you may have an older, unsupported version installed. Though the pypi page for `fbprophet` is still a top result on Google, I believe you actually want to download and install the `prophet` package which is now on version 1.0.1.  So `pip install prophet`, not `pip install fbprophet`.

Comment: Thank you! I have just tried that but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your error, but I believe I know why the fit is failing.
The data you are trying to fit are closing stock prices for >500 stocks.  When plotted using `data_to_use.plot.scatter(x='ds', y='y', s=0.01)`, you get:

[image: all_stocks_plt]

I believe the fit is failing because it is simply struggling to converge to a reasonable solution as mentioned in [this `pystan` discourse thread](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/pystan-error-with-optimizing/11236).  When I naively try to fit this data, it doesn't fail but instead gives a nearly horizontal line prediction near `y = 100` with very large error bars.

Depending on what you're trying to do, I'd suggest either picking one stock by `Name`, for example:

```
data_to_use_pcln = pandas_df[pandas_df.Name.eq('PCLN')].filter(['date', 'close'])
data_to_use_pcln.columns = ['ds', 'y']
data_to_use_pcln['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(data_to_use_pcln['ds'])
```

or summing all stock prices together for each day like this:

```
summed_data = pandas_df.groupby('date').agg('sum').reset_index().filter(['date', 'close'])
summed_data.columns = ['ds', 'y']
summed_data['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(summed_data['ds'])
```

Passing the summed data to `model.fit()` gives a reasonable solution:

[image: market_forecast]